# Use on-demand dynamic feature module in universal apk on device with no Play Services

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module

We have a dynamic feature module in our app. We are going to start supplying this module `on-demand`. So I'm working through [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#request). I see that I have to use [`SplitInstallManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/splitinstall/SplitInstallManager) in the Play core library.

However I also need to build a universal apk (which automagically bundles the dynamic feature module) for the non-Play-Services phones we support. So what will happen when I call `SplitInstallManager` in this case? Since the phones don't have Play Services will the calls to `SplitInstallManager` work? Will the calls to `SplitInstallManager` know this is a universal apk and that the dynamic module is already included? Can I assume that the `StateUpdatedListener.onStateUpdate()` will automatically pass a `SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED` update?